# Limit number of users in a security group

Tags: permissions, security, office-365, groups, user-accounts

I've a requirement like there should be only one user with some specific permissions on a given site. We should not allow Admin to add more than one user with those permissions, So I created a group with those permissions, now can I limit number of users in that group? or is there any workaround for this requirement?  I'm using office365.

Answer (score 2):

On premises you can use this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.speventreceivertype.aspx

In Office 365
You can in theory create an app that will handle the administration of those groups for you. However you'd have to hide the original permission management page (master page changes).